# Can I block prerender children on React Fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fiber

I wrote  component on React Fiber.
This component receive 1 cond props, and that is true, render children.

```
"use strict";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface IfProps {
  cond: boolean;
}

export class If extends React.Component<IfProps, {}> {
  render() {
    const {cond, children} = this.props;

    if (cond) {
      return children;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class TopComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let str: any = null;

    return (
      <div>
        <If cond={str != null}>
          This part not showed.
          {str.length}
        </If>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TopComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Before React Fiber, this code works. But now, React Fiber causes error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

I guess that React Fiber render children before  component is rendered.
But this behavior break  component.

Can I stop prerender children of  component?

Comment: Are you sure this worked before? You can't construct the children of `<If>` without first evaluating `str.length`, and that hasn't changed with Fiber..

Comment: Sorry, 
I was wrong. I tried the code on React 15, and same error caused...

sample code
https://jsfiddle.net/kmdsbng/9gj83n6x/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case isn't that react doesn't accept a `null` return value. (Which it does [`ReactComponent.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render))
But your the children will get evaluated before they get handed over to the `If` component which means that `str.length` throws the error you're seeing.

[Basic example](https://jsfiddle.net/L1dyzed0/) based on your code.